How can progress bar be added into the action button in R Shiny?
Suppose I have one action button in shiny application which helps user to download a report.
I want to show the progress bar onto the button itself. So when the action button is clicked, the progress bar should appear into the button and once downloading is done, it would show 'Done' in the action button label.
For shiny progress bar example, we could consider the below code (taken for posit progress bar article)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot # Re-run when button is clicked

    # Create 0-row data frame which will be used to store data
    dat <- data.frame(x = numeric(0), y = numeric(0))

    withProgress(message = 'Making plot', value = 0, {
      # Number of times we'll go through the loop
      n <- 10

      for (i in 1:n) {
        # Each time through the loop, add another row of data. This is
        # a stand-in for a long-running computation.
        dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)))

        # Increment the progress bar, and update the detail text.
        incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("Doing part", i))

        # Pause for 0.1 seconds to simulate a long computation.
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
    })

    plot(dat$x, dat$y)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(basicPage(
  plotOutput('plot', width = "300px", height = "300px"),
  actionButton('goPlot', 'Go plot')
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

And here is one example what I am looking for.
